# Grails Plugin Maven Integration

Tags: grails, maven-2, grails-plugin

I'm trying to create Mavenized Grails application. Everything works fine but as I understood all the dependencies (all .jars like mysql-connector and also all grails (public) plugins like spring-security-core plugin) should be listed in pom.xml.

The thing is that I don't know how to include public grails plugins (is there any Maven repository for that, or should I include used plugins into my local repo?). Or is the proper way how to handle grails plugin to list them in "application.properties" and let the grails to manage these plugins?

Thank you for any comment.:-)

Mateo

Comment: Why not to allow grails to manage his plugins? Maven is useful when you have some extra jar, that are needed by your own code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify your plugin dependencies in `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`, for example:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {

  plugins { 
    runtime ':hibernate:1.2.1' 
  }
}
```

### Update

In response to your comments below, a plugin dependency specified in `BuildConfig.groovy` (or `application.properties`) will still be resolved by Grails rather than Maven. I don't think there's any way that you can get Maven to resolve a Grails plugin dependency, because Maven can only work with JAR dependencies in Maven repositories. Remember, Grails plugins are not (typically) available from Maven repositories.

If you want to hand as much control as possible over to Maven, you can try excluding the JARs from your plugin dependencies, e.g.

```
plugins {
    runtime( "org.grails.plugins:hibernate:1.2.1" ) {
        excludes "javassist"
    }
}
```

and add them to your `pom.xml` instead. Here be dragons (see below).

### Editorializing

FWIW, unless you really have to build your Grails project with Maven (e.g. because another Maven project depends on it), my advice would be **don't**. I say this because Maven is very much a second-class citizen in the world of Grails build tools. The usual way to build a Grails app is using the built-in GAnt commands. Future versions of Grails will move towards Gradle as the default build tool, so it seems that Maven will be an afterthought for the forseeable future

Comment: The thing is that I want (need) to have all dependencies in pom.xml in order to let the Maven solve all dependencies. I think that following code let Grails to solve the hibernate dependency. Why wouldn't you Maven integration? I thought that this is the most recommended way how to build Grails project because of other project, Continuous Integration, etc.

Comment: Ok, now I understand! Thank you for your explanation, I'm going to learn Gradle a little bit.:-)

Comment: If I had to choose between Maven and Gradle, I would choose Gradle, but then if I had to choose between sawing off my finger with a rusty blade and Maven, I still probably wouldn't choose Maven

Comment: Note that with [Grails 2.1](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0.RC2/guide/introduction.html#whatsNew21) the plugin no longer uses Ivy, but lets Maven handle all dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Grails plugins are included at the source level. A plugin zip is expanded, and the plugin source is compiled as part of the grails build process.

Since 2.0, grails can use binary plugins. You can depend on plain old JARS if those jars represent binary grails plugins.

Binary grails plugins can be referenced by normal maven coordinates.

Your project's BuildConfig.groovy is where you specify maven repositories and binary plugins.